# WP7 Get navigated page url WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Is there anyway to get the url that your browser has navigated to and set it to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the Navigated event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated(v=VS.92).aspx and use the Uri to set your string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.navigatingeventargs.uri(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: public event EventHandler<NavigationEventArgs> Navigated                                                             public string Uri { get; internal set; }   ?

Comment: Yes - use the Navigating or Navigated events.

Comment: so sting called "string" will have the text in it?